# How to call services.Configure from Configure method in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net-core

In ConfigureServices() in my Startup.cs file I call this

```
if (services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().IsDevelopment()) {
 services.Configure<EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("WebServicesDevelopment"));
} else {
 services.Configure<EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("WebServicesProduction"));
}
```

I'm getting a build warning saying

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'

How do I call this from Configure() with the IApplicationBuilder?

Comment: Why do you want to move it? The two methods are meant for performing two seperate tasks. You configure services in ConfigureServices and the application pipeline in Configure

Comment: because when I build I'm getting a warning saying "Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'"

Comment: sorry! let me edit my post to explain a little further.

Comment: oh, I guess I can just inject "IServiceCollection" into "Configure()"?

Comment: No don't do that. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

First, check [multiple environments support in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You could configure environment specific sections to avoid `if-else` statement in code.

*Now assume the above does not work for you:*

You should avoid building container in `ConfigureServices` method as per the reason stated in the warning message.

Instead, you should use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-di-services-to-configure-options):

```
services.AddOptions<EnvironmentSettings>()
    .Configure<IConfiguration, IWebHostEnvironment>(
        (settings, config, env) =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                config.GetSection("WebServicesDevelopment").Bind(settings);
            }
            else
            {
                config.GetSection("WebServicesProduction").Bind(settings);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the warning states, calling `BuildServiceProvider` can have unintended side effects and is an anti-pattern. Services are meant to be configured in `ConfigureServices` and we have all the necessary tools to perform conditional configuration based on environment. Simply inject `IWebHostEnvironment` in the constructor for the `Startup` class and configure your services appropriately:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env /* take dependency on environment */)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env; // store environment
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure based on environment
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        { 
            services.Configure<EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("WebServicesDevelopment"));
        } 
        else 
        {
           // non-dev services
           services.Configure<EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("WebServicesProduction"));
        }
    }
}
```

See the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1 search for the phrase "Only the following service types can be injected"

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-based-startup-class-and-methods) has more information, including how you can even have multiple `Startup` classes or multiple `ConfigureServices` methods (per environment)

Comment: hi pink. I think the issue I have to solve is, in your if statement, where you check the env for dev, I need to run this "services.Configure<EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("WebServicesDevelopment"));" it fills the EnvironmentSettings object with all the appropriate data it pulls from the appsettings file. I need to figure out how to do it in the configure method. Or conversely, determine if dev/prod in the ConfigureServices method, either will work!

Comment: No you don't need to do it in Configure. You need to/must do it in ConfigureServices. My example shows exactly how to determine if dev/prod within ConfigureServices. I'm not following your concern. Add `services.Configure<EnvironmentSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("WebServicesDevelopment"))` right after "// Dev services" in the above code and the other version in the else block